# Does not work 'WHILE GETOPS' in BASH script

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, getopt, getopts

I have a script with two parameters, host and domain name of this host. Look:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
log=/var/log/upgrade_old_ALLOS.log.$data

function show_help {
echo "Usage: $0 -h host -d dns"
echo "For example: ./upgrade_old_ALLOS.sh -h wwe.com01 -d wwe.com"
}

function logging {
echo $(date) "______" "$1" | tee -a $log
}

while getopts h:d:s opt; do
case $opt in
s)
    show_help
    exit 0
    ;;
h)
if [ -z "$OPTARG" ]; then
    logging "Error. Name of host is not provided"
    show_help
    exit 1
else
    host="$OPTARG"
fi
;;
d)
if [ -z "$OPTARG" ]; then
    logging "Error. Domain is not provided"
    show_help
    exit 1
else
    dns="$OPTARG"
fi
;;
*)
    show_help >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
done

if [ -z "$host" ]; then
    logging "Host was not provided"
    show_help
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$dns" ]; then
    logging "Domain was not provided"
    show_help
    exit 1
fi

host="$1"
logging "$host"
echo $host > /root/tag
dns="$2"
logging "$dns"
echo $dns >> /root/tag

if [ -f "/root/tag" ] ; then
    hostname=$(awk NR==1 "/root/tag")
    domain=$(awk NR==2 "/root/tag")
    logging "$hostname"
    logging "$domain"
else
    logging "Not found /root/tag"
    exit 1
fi
```

I should execute this script, like this:

```
./upgrade_old_ALLOS.sh -h wwe.com01 -d wwe.com
```

But in a result file, i have this:

```
-h
wwe.com01
```

But i should have:

```
wwe.com01
wwe.com
```

Where i have error ? Please help.

Comment: Why do you do this: `host="$1"`? And once you have done it, why does the result surprise you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the value of `host` and `dns` after the getopts ... your script works as intended

```
./upgrade_old_ALLOS.sh -h wwe.com01 -d wwe.com
$1 : -h
$2 : wwe.com01
$3 : -d
$4 : wwe.com

host="$1" => host = "-h"
dns="$2"  => dns = "wwe.com01"
```

Remove `host="$1"` and `dns="$2"` and it will do what you want